# Way to add data from DataTable object to Oracle table

Tags: c#, oracle, tableadapter

I need a very simple way to insert data from DataTable object to Oracle table. I'm using c#.

I have the data in my datatable.I just need to now insert that data into a oracle table.

I know that some like this needs to be done

foreach (datatable.row)
 insert into table values()

---

This is what I tried but it did not at all work.

```
dt1= dt.Clone(); 
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) { 
     dt1.ImportRow(dr); 
} 
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++) { 
    Console.WriteLine("---in------"); 
    OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand(
        "insert into t_test_position (position_id,position_desc) values ('"
        + dt1.Rows[i]["position_id"].ToString() + "','" 
        + dt1.Rows[i]["position_desc"].ToString() + "')", oraconn);   
    ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: do you have a database connection?

Comment: dt1= dt.Clone();
          
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            { dt1.ImportRow(dr);
                            }
    for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("---in------");
                        OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand("insert into t_test_position (position_id,position_desc) values ('" + dt1.Rows[i]["position_id"].ToString() + "','" + dt1.Rows[i]["position_desc"].ToString() + "')", oraconn);
                        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

Comment: This is what I tried but it did not at all work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a temporary table oracle. I'm having exactly the same problem right now and the best solution I found is to change the temporary table to normal table.